# How to setup shared tooling for a lerna monorepo?

Tags: javascript, typescript, eslint, lerna, monorepo

I have a typescript lerna monorepo with just a few packages currently, I would like to know the best practice on setting up shared tooling such as; jest, eslint, prettier...

Having read various guides, the two options I see are;

- adding this to the root package (cons: polluting the root package, is this an issue? why?)
- creating a tools package and somehow hoisting all the dependencies into all the other packages.

Any advice, guides etc would be very much appreciated.

Comment: Can you help with some more information, are you using NPM or Yarn Workspaces?

Comment: @LuísBrito I am using NPM, but could make the switch to Yarn if needed!

Comment: Both are good. If you need specific rules on some package it might be better to have a base eslint package and override it as needed on target packages